# Stange stream of HTTP GET requests in apache logs, from amazon ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, http, curl, flooding

I just had a look at my apache logs, and I see a lot of very similar requests:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (i386-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.24.0 \
    NSS/3.13.5.0 zlib/1.2.5 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2
Host: [my_domain].org
Accept: */*
```

- there's a steady stream of those, about 2 or 3 per minute;
- they all request the same domain and resource (there are slight variations in user agent version numbers);
- they come form a lot of different IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, in blocs that belong to amazon ec2 (in Singapore, Japan, Ireland and the USA).

I tried to look for an explanation online, or even just similar stories, but couldn't find any.

Has anyone got a clue as to what this is? It doesn't look malicious per say, but it's just annoying me, and I couldn't find any more information about it.

I first suspected it could be a bot checking if my server is still up, but:

1. I don't remember subscribing to such a service;
2. why would it need to check my site twice every minute;
3. why doesn't it use a clearly identifying fqdn.

Or, should I send this question to amazon, via their abuse contact?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have content someone might want to crawl regularly?

Comment: What do you mean by "clearly identifying fqdn" doesn't `Host: [my_domain].org` count?

Comment: @ceejayoz when querying the root of my domain, the answer is actually a "302 Found" redirection to "/blog/" (caused by a apache RewriteRule), which the curl bot never requests afterwards.

Comment: @Ladadadada I meant "clearly identifying fqdn" for the curl client. There is no PTR record for these – well, I'm not sure whether EC2 would allow that, but here, neither the User-Agent not the client IP address help me identify who is persistently querying my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're seeing unexpected traffic or malicious traffic coming to your servers from AWS, you should submit an abuse case via http://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/AWSAbuse so they can get in touch with whoever is sending the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an ttack being performed on your system. You can use network Acl to block the IP addresses or use a WAF